# How do I make a Python Openshift run a certain python file?

Tags: openshift

I would like to run a certain python file whenever the OpenShift app starts. I have tried many things, like in the wsgi.py file running `execfile("thefilename.py")` which didn't work!

I was hoping to get some help with this! Thanks so much!

Comment: What is you are actually trying to do this for? Are you just wanting to run a pre deploy action, or are you trying to replace the default WSGI server? If just trying to run a pre deploy action, that is what action hooks are for. https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/action-hooks.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton looking to start a python script when the server starts.

Comment: As a continuous background task, or to perform a one off action. If it is a one off action, you can use the ``deploy`` action hook for which I referenced documentation. A continuous background task is a bit more problematic if that is what you want. What is the script doing.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton How would you go about solving the "A continuous background task". I want to deploy a web server in one pod and a collector script in another pod that simply collects data to feed a database. The web server pod simply serves the database.

Comment: @mart1n Please create a new question which explains in detail what your issue is. Don't ask questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Running from a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64"
export PATH="/var/lib/openshift/<your ssh id>/python//virtenv/venv/bin:/var/lib/openshift/<your ssh id>/python//bin:/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin"
source ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/activate
python pathtofile/yourfile.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to run within a python script.  It should run the file in the background.

```
Import os
os.system("python  pathtofile/thefilename.py &")
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Make sure you have the correct path to your file.

Comment: Also,  you might need the full path to the python executable.  It's been a while since I have done this and forget if python is set in the PATH

Comment: mod_wsgi (pid=498744): Target WSGI script '/var/lib/openshift/*************/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.

Comment: You better post code.  I think you are running out in the wrong place.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python
import os
from yourapplication import app as application

os.system("python thefilename.py &")`

Comment: You should put your code in your original question.  It looks like you are trying to run a script file that executes your python file.  I posted another answer.  Maybe rewrite your question to be more precise what you actually want to do.